# Why `obj.method is obj._class__method` is False

Tags: python

I was reading the docs of classes in python and I faced **9.6. Private Variables** which there was written

> Since there is a valid use-case for class-private members (namely to avoid name clashes of names with names defined by subclasses), there is limited support for such a mechanism, called name mangling. Any identifier of the form __spam (at least two leading underscores, at most one trailing underscore) is textually replaced with _classname__spam, where classname is the current class name with leading underscore(s) stripped. This mangling is done without regard to the syntactic position of the identifier, as long as it occurs within the definition of a class.

It made me curious about that `obj.update is obj._Mapping__update` should return True. But it doesn't. I checked the ID of both of them and they were the same. So... what's happening here?

```
In [1]: class Mapping: 
   ...:     def __init__(self, iterable): 
   ...:         self.items_list = [] 
   ...:         self.__update(iterable) 
   ...:  
   ...:     def update(self, iterable): 
   ...:         for item in iterable: 
   ...:             self.items_list.append(item) 
   ...:  
   ...:     __update = update   # private copy of original update() method 
   ...:                                                                                                                                                                                                             

In [2]: obj = Mapping([])                                                                                                                                                                                           

In [3]: obj.update == obj._Mapping__update                                                                                                                                                                          
Out[3]: True

In [4]: print(id(obj.update), id(obj._Mapping__update))                                                                                                                                                             
139655901847816 139655901847816

In [5]: obj.update is obj._Mapping__update                                                                                                                                                                          
Out[5]: False
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you access methods of an instance, a ***new*** bound method is returned each time:

```
>>> class X:
...     def foo(self): pass
...     __foo = foo
...
>>> inst = X()
>>> a = inst.foo
>>> b = inst._X__foo
>>> a
<bound method X.foo of <__main__.X object at 0x7f62f41144a8>>
>>> b
<bound method X.foo of <__main__.X object at 0x7f62f41144a8>>
```

These two objects will compare equal (because they reference the same underlying method), but they won't have the same identity:

```
>>> a == b, id(a), id(b), a is b
(True, 140062981356744, 140062980414856, False)
```

Note that if you call `id()` *directly* on an attribute, a new bound method will be created and thrown away each time, and there is no guarantee that Python won't re-use the previous id. So it's important to save the objects to a variable before making such comparisons.

To compare the identity of the underlying methods, you should use the class:

```
>>> X._X__foo is X.foo
True
```